# How to clone the iPhone Camera app's gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon

I have finished [the development of an app](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/seeking-advice-to-improve-the-design-of-my-minimalist-calculator). Now I have to worry about the icon ;-)

To align with the built-in app, I want the gradient of the my icon background looks like the built-in Camera app, i.e. a light source form the top.

[image]

How can I clone the gradient in Photoshop? For example, can I take `RGB` values from a few reference points (top, middle, button) of the Camera icon to deine the gradient of my icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you essentially answered the question yourself.

> can I take RGB values from a few reference points (top, middle, button) of the Camera icon to deine the gradient of my icon?

That's exactly what you do, but for this one you don't need a middle value for *this* gradient.

You can make your life easier by first finding a higher resolution version of the icon. I did so by running a reverse image search with Google Images (click the camera icon in the search box).

The RGB value for the top of the gradient is #F8F8F8, the bottom is #919095. Set those as your foreground/background, apply a gradient overlay to your layer, and select the `Foreground to Background` gradient preset. If it comes out upside down, tick the `Reverse` checkbox.

If you want to re-color the gradient but have it look similar, add a `Color Overlay` layer effect and set the Blend Mode to something like Overlay (I usually just cycle through them to see which one looks nice)

Here's what I was able to come up with:

[image: Camera Icon]

Comment: Thanks @John, any chance you can share the `PSD`? I am not sure I understand where there is _one_ layer or _two_ (one for gradient, one for the background)? What I means is, what if I want to clone gradient but _not_ the color, say, a yellowish icon with similar light source and gradient?

Comment: @ohho, the end result should be at least two layers: 1 for the gradient, and 1 or more for whatever you're putting on top of the gradient (the lens in this case). The gradient is a Shape object with a Gradient Overlay effect applied. I have edited my answer to include a screenshot of Photoshop for (hopefully) some clarity. Here are the colored version's layer effects: http://i.imgur.com/N7NnyPr.png